brython in iframe nags about:srcdoc#__main__ is not a url
I'm resctircted to use iframe
<html style='height: 100%'>
 <head>          
 <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3/brython.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3/brython_stdlib.js'></script> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
  <canvas id='my_canvas' > </canvas>
  <script>
    __BRYTHON__.brython_path = 
 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3/brython.min.js'
    __BRYTHON__.script_path  = 
 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3/brython.min.js' 
    console.log('asd', __BRYTHON__.script_path )
    </script> 
<script type='text/python3'>
from browser import document, html , timer
 
time_elapsed = 0
canvas = document["my_canvas"]
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
 
def draw_circle(t): 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    radius = 50 + 30 * math.sin(t / 10)
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(150, 150, radius, 0, 2 * math.pi)
    ctx.stroke()

timer.set_interval(lambda: draw_circle(timer.time_elapsed() ), 50)
    
</script>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

and I get :
Uncaught Error: not a url: about:srcdoc#__main__
    at $B.strip_host (brython.min.js:1:2062)
    at run_scripts (brython.min.js:1:58001)
    at $B.parser.brython (brython.min.js:1:55126)
    at ev.target.body.onload (brython.min.js:1:52395)

